# How difficult is it to switch libraries from C++/SFML to C++/SDL

Tags: android, c++, sdl, sfml

I'm developing a game and understand that SFML is not currently compatible with Android, but SDL is. How similar are SFML and SDL? Can code written in SFML be easily converted to SDL? What are the main differences between the two game libraries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Tutorial: Building SFML for Android](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Building-SFML-for-Android)

Comment: The ideas behind those libs are the same: abstract out the platform. SDL is old and relatively ugly C, more functional, used by many game developers and even some AAA titles. SFML is younger, less functional, a beautiful idiomatic C++. Conversion is, basically, rewriting everything that uses library functions from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code conversion between those libs may be such a pain if your game is currently in an advanced state. The main difference is that SDL uses more complicated functions and will lead you to self writing a wrapper which might take an unnecessary time.

If you are planning to switch to a different lib which supports Android I wouldn't recommend SDL since it's not the most functional lib that I've tried, and it won't let you use float pixels which translates into a bad graphic fluency. I'd strongly recommend to go with [Allegro](http://liballeg.org/download.html) 5.1.x, it's a little bit more difficult than SFML but very functional and easier than SDL, it's got nice support and it's compatible with plenty of OS.

Comment: Yes, the latest unstable version [5.1.13](http://download.gna.org/allegro/allegro-unstable/5.1.13/allegro-5.1.13.zip) (which is pretty stable) is fully compatible with android.